# WebFriverAgentRunner build cannot get Listening to USB

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, xcuitest

Appium: 1.15.0
Node:V12.10.0
Xcode:11.0
Real Device: 12.4.1

Cannot get listening to USB when build and test WebDriverAgentLibRunner.

I have installed anything I should have such as libimobiledevice , carthage, ios-deploy and xcpretty. I followed the instructions of setting up WebDriverAgentLib and runner from Npm. But still cannot get the expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots show that the WebDriverAgent was compiled correctly and installed on your device. You can also see the WebDriverAgent launched correctly and you can interact with it over HTTP. So that looks pretty good.

You do have an error in your `JSON_HEADER` variable; the correct definition is `JSON_HEADER='-H "Content-Type: application/json"'`. You added `accept: application/json` which throws curl off guard (and hence the `Could not resolve host: application`) errors.

So you probably want to fix that.

Apart from that, what was your "expected result"?